# How to get $(this) on a delegated event

Tags: jquery, html

I have page that contains the following links

```
<a id="21561" class="delete_item" href="#" name="baseMenu">
<img class="icons" src="../images/delete.gif">
</a>

<a id="219350" class="delete_item" href="#" name="menuOptions">
<img class="icons" src="images/delete.gif">
</a>
```

The only difference between the 2 links is the *name attribute.*

The issue that I am having, is that these links are being injected into the HTML document dynamically via `$.post()` method

I am trying to get the name attribute when the delete link has been clicked on, but it doesn't seem to work when I use it in conjunction using the  `$(this)` attribute.

Can someone please help me get the `$(this)` attr for the .delete_item link on click event.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
$(document).on("click",  $(".delete_item") ,   function(){


var test = $(".delete_item", this);
console.log(test);
return false; //We just want get the value for now
no need to parse the rest of the code. We now it works


//rest of the ajax code .......
 )
```

Comment: How to use event delegation correctly is explained in the offical **jQuery tutorial**: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/. I suggest you have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the the jQuery function call in the delegated event definition, I think that is the root of the problem. Once you fix that you should just be able to use `$(this)`.

An example:

```
$(document).on("click",  ".delete_item" ,   function(){

var test = $(this);
console.log(test);
return false; //We just want get the value for now no need to parse the rest of the code. We now it works

//rest of the ajax code .......
 });
```

Comment: Re *"jquery brackets"*: `$` is just a function, so `$(...)` is a function call. I understand what you are saying, but you make it sound like jQuery is more magically than it really is.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I know I just couldn't think of a better term for it, I'll change it. :)

Comment: @Phaeze Wow. I can't believe I didn't realize that. I removed the jQuery function and it did work. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_item" , function(){

var that= $(this);
console.log(that);
return false; //We just want get the value for now


 });
```

Comment: The `var` will have to be named something other than `this`, though. The keyword can't be assigned or declared as a local variable.

Comment: you can try console.log($(this)); only or in variable define $(this)

Comment: While this is correct, `var this` is still a syntax error.

Comment: No if you use this in other function in on click for example var is correct

Comment: When I try to evaluate `function foo() { var this = 42; }`, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token this`. I can assure you that you can't use `this` as an lvalue. Assigning to `this` is just not possible (@Phaeze). However, I'm happy to be convinced otherwise if you create a working example in http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Just like `if`, [`this` is a keyword](https://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1), so you can't do `var if` or `var this`. If you remove the `var` and just have `this = $(this)`, you get a different error: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

Comment: sorry you true this word is keyword you chan set other name in variable or use $(this)

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to pass the event and get it from that:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete_item", function(event){

    //Our target (this)
    var target = event.target;

    var test = $(".delete_item", target );
    console.log(test);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 1) You have to pass a selector to `.on`, not a jQuery object 2) All the testing for `event` and `event.srcElement` is unnecessary since jQuery already passes unified event object to the handler.